# Reflecting column updates in a discussion board

Tags: 2007, discussion-board

Consider a discussion board created from scratch in MOSS07 with the following additional column:

- Issue Status

In the process of use:

> A user posts a discussion with a default status of Active (context of Discussion).
>   Somebody
>   replies and sets Issue Status (which at this point, is in context of Message) to Closed.

The discussion should have its Issue Status changed from Active to Closed.  Any thoughts about doing this?  I've tried a few workflow tasks but to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I am a newb at SharePoint 2007 and ran into a similar issue but could not find a good way to solve this other then only showing the status in the first post and relying on the original poster and/or discussion board admin make the change.

For more info on this approach go to this link:
http://referpages.com/wp/2011/01/track-items-by-active-or-closed-in-sharepoint-discussion-board/

Hope this helps but I am sure there is a better solution.